# Filtrar información de firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

Estoy trabajando con firebase y tengo una duda..
En mi aplicación los usuarios entrar con su cuenta gmail, en firebase guardo el ID del usuario e información de su pedido, estoy implementando un método que encontré y funciona pero como hago que solo me muestre los datos del ID x

```
listBeer() {
return ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  children: [
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: db
          .collection('Beer')
          .snapshots(), 

      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
            children: snapshot.data.documents
                .map((doc) => buildItem(doc))
                .toList(),
          );
        } else {
          return SizedBox();
        }
      },
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas usar el ID `x` que deseas y ponerlo dentro del filtro de documento, así :

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Beer').document('tu_id_aqui').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        var userDocument = snapshot.data;
        return buildItem(userDocument);
      }
  );
}
```